# what is difference between .submit() vs :submit?

Tags: jquery

Someone tell me the difference between .submit() vs :submit. When & where to use with a simple example please.

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/ Go nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) is a method. That means you need to call it when you want to *trigger* a form submission

```
$("#form").submit()
```

[`:submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) is a selector helper to find specifically buttons that submits

```
$("button:submit")
```

You can find very valuable examples on the jquery doc pages linked in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

[`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) is a function, used to submit a form. [`:submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) is a selector, used to identify `<input type="submit">` elements.

Example:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="submit" id="mySubmitButton" value="Click me!">
</form>

$('#myForm').submit(); // submits the form
$(':submit'); // selects the submit button
```

Answer (score 3):

- `.submit()` is a function that submits a form.
- `:submit` is a selector to find submit buttons

Answer (score 1):

The `:submit` pseudo-class will match `<input>` elements with a `type` of `submit`. The `.submit()` method is completely different; depending on what you pass it, it will either submit a form or add an event listener to one.

Here's a quick example:

```
$(':submit'); // will return all <input type="submit">
$('form:submit'); // shouldn't ever return anything
$('form').submit(); // submits all forms
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}); // disallows any forms to be submitted
```

For more information, see [the jQuery API documentation on `.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 1):

`$("html_element").X().Y().Z()` - **function**: do something with the selected html_element

eaxample - in this case do something= modify the css property:

$("li").css({"color":"orange"});

---

`$("html_element:X")` - **selector**: filter somehow the selected html_element

eaxample - in this case all "li" elements was reduced to only the first one

$("li:nth-child(1)").css({"color":"red"});